# Nativebase: How to render an Icon?

Tags: react-native, native-base

The [documentation](https://docs.nativebase.io/icon#icon) says "Use a third-party icon library ( such as @expo/vector-icons ), with as prop."

I don't really know what that means, but let's say i want to render the Ionicon's home icon.

`<Icon as="Ionicons" name="home" size={size} color={color} />`

This just renders the question mark. So any idea how to use this?

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you're using expo:**

```
yarn add @expo/vector-icons
```

Use Icon in jsx/tsx:

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

<Icon as="Ionicons" name="home" size={size} color={color} />
```

**if you're not using expo, you can use `react-native-vector-icons` instead:**

```
yarn add react-native-vector-icons
```

don't forget to run `pod update` and add `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"` to `android/app/build.gradle`

Use Icon in jsx/tsx:

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

<Icon as="Ionicons" name="home" size={size} color={color} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You are providing Ionicons in String, while it is a Component. The correct way is:

```
<Icon as={Ionicons} name="home" size={size} color={color} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember about `import` ;-) Have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/expo/vector-icons) carefully?
To check this out You can use the editor from the `examples` in the **Nativebase** [documentation.](https://docs.nativebase.io/icon#icon)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class IconExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Ionicons name="home" size={32} color="green" />;
  }
}
```

Comment: So nativebase doesn't really include any icon libraries, you need to install them seprately?

Comment: As we can read in the Nativebase documentation:
They "provides a set of commonly used interface icons. So you can directly use them in your project. All our icons are create using createIcon function from NativeBase" . When comes about "Ionicons" This library is part of the expo package, so if you are using expo you can simply use it.